# Helm pass range of properties

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm tring to pass values ( the description can be ["First description","Second description"], but is the same).

```
templates:
  description: 
   - First description
   - Second description
  name: 
   - First name
   - Second name
  references: 
   - First reference
   - Second reference
```

for template property:

```
templates:
- description: First description
  name: First name
  references:
  - First reference
- description: Second description
  name: Second name
  references:
  - Second reference
```

I tried with

```
{{- range $key,$values := .Values.templates }}
    - {{ $key }}: {{$values}}
      {{ $key }}: {{$values}}
      {{ $key }}: {{$values}}
{{- end }}
```

but I'm far from the result.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve; just to rearrange the first set of Helm values into the second format?  Can you change the Helm values structure to match the layout you need?

Comment: Thanks. I will change the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some logical judgment to achieve, this conversion is not a good solution

values.yaml

```yaml
templates:
  description:
    - "First-description"
    - "Second-description"
    - "33333-description"
  name:
    - "First-name"
    - "Second-name"
    - "333-name"
  references:
    - "First-reference"
    - "Second-reference"
    - "3333-reference"
```

templateX.yaml

```yaml
templates: 
{{- if $.Values.templates }}
{{- range $i, $_ := $.Values.templates.name }}
{{- range $k, $v := $.Values.templates }}
{{- if eq $k "description" }}
- {{ $k }}: {{ index $v $i }}
{{- else if eq $k "references" }}
  {{ $k }}:
  - {{ index $v $i }}
{{- else }}
  {{ $k }}: {{ index $v $i }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

---

A better way is to try to update the definition format of the data in values.yaml

like this:

values.yaml

```yaml
templates:
  - description: First-description
    name: First-name
    references:
      - First-reference
  - description: Second-description
    name: Second-name
    references:
      - Second-reference
  - description: 3333-description
    name: 3333-name
    references:
      - 3333-reference
  - description: 4444-description
    name: 4444-name
    references:
      - 4444-reference
```

templateX.yaml

```yaml
templates: 
  {{- toYaml $.Values.templates | nindent 2 }}
```

Comment: What if I want to add more not only two templates ? Example this properties description, name and references to be added by --set . How to change nindent 2 to work with?

Comment: ```nindent``` is just an indentation, see [helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#nindent) for details

Comment: No matter how many you write below the templates, you can fill them in this way，see above, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

How to set these parameters with `--set`. Example:

- I want when add --set number=First and
- --set number=Second

This number to be set for all words where I have First and Second.

```
templates:
  - description: First-description
    name: First-name
    references:
      - First-reference
  - description: Second-description
    name: Second-name
    references:
      - Second-reference
```

Comment: see [helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) for details.  For example, if you want to set ```name: Second-name```, you can write like this : ```--set templates[1].name=Sed-name```